# Forms App crashes after splash screen on iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin Forms app, that works perfectly on Android and iOS emulators, but if I try to deploy it on iOS device it crashes once I see my first screen.

sometimes it writes in log a MT1107 error, but sometimes not

here is my iOS device log:
http://pastebin.com/uGp5K7Pg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check line 70 of your PasteBin:

```
Sequence contains no elements (System.InvalidOperationException)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[UIViewController] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.<.ctor>b__0 (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TabletMasterDetailRenderer sender) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter+<>c__DisplayClass4`1[Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TabletMasterDetailRenderer].<Subscribe>b__3 (System.Object sender, System.Object args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It seems you are wrapping a `MasterDetailPage` into a `NavigationPage`. On iOS (more specifically: iPad), this uses a `UISplitViewController`, which must not be embedded into a `UINavigationController`. Xamarin.Forms uses the native controls whenever possible.

Try checking the device OS and idiom: if you are on iPad, don't wrap a `NavigationPage` around your pages.

Comment: @valdetero as soon as I check it and it will work I'll mark it as answer of course, unfortunately my current task is some other critical bug, but I'll definitely close this issue today ;)
all I can do right now is vote up for this, seems like it is true, but didn't check it yet

Comment: @Krumelur that was it, my app still crashes on start but now for differ reasons, they are in my code, thanks for help